# Out of memory error when I try to read from xlsx

Tags: r

I want to import a sheet from a xlsx workbook so I try:

```
library(xlsx)
data<-read.xlsx("m.xlsx", sheetName ="me", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and get the error

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

What can I do to import this file?

This xlsx workbook contains 500 rows and 40 columns

Comment: Try `openxlsx` package

Comment: same error using `read.xlsx2`?

Comment: I've had the same problem, and not been able to fix it.  My eventual solution was to obtain the original spreadsheet, and export it as a ".csv" file.  I had no problem reading that.  If your circumstances allow, that may be the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

You need to increase the Java heap size. You can do this in R for `rJava` (which powers `xlsx`) by adding a value for the `-Xmx` flag, like so:

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )
```

will increase heap size to 4 GB

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx8g" )
```

will increase heap size to 8 GB, etc. It's best to increase it a little at a time until the problem goes away.

Note that you'll want to do this *before* the JVM is initialized, i.e., before you load the package. More [here](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/726).